# How to get IPs via DHCP, through a router from another DHCP server?

Tags: openbsd, dhcp, openwrt, router

ISP -> OpenBSD box -> Wireless router

We have an OpenBSD machine that connects directly to the internet, has dhcp/dns cache "server" on it, and forwards the connection to clients via ethernet cable/switch.

But it would be good if the network would work via wifi too. For that, probably the best solution is to have a wireless router, since PCI/USB wireless sticks in the OpenBSD box wouldn't serve well, ex.: N network at 50 Mbit/sec wireless.

We already have a router with OpenWRT 14.07. But here is the problem:

**Question**: How can we set the OpenWRT router to use the DHCP server of the OpenBSD box to give IPs for the clients? Currently the OpenWRT router has its own DHCP server and that gives other subnet than the OpenBSD box.

How can the OpenBSD box give IP via DHCP via the wireless router's clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Dumb AP / Access Point Only

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/dumbap

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure your wireless router to behave as a simple Wireless Access Point/bridge and everything will Just Work.